# Project specific Mantis states

Tags: bug-tracking, mantis

I'm working in a company using one Mantis bug tracker hosting several projects.

The project I am working on needs specific statuses and I don't want these to be seeable in other project pages.

I see in the doc how to add a status but they seem to be global and not project specific.

The only way I see how to do it is to add global states and remove them from all other projects' workflows.

Do you know if (and how) it is possible to add project specific workflows ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything you can set in config_inc.php can also be defined in the database, either globally (all projects) or for specific projects.

You can do this using the *Manage | Manage Configuration | Configuration Report* page; at the bottom of the page, a section lets you define custom config options. Define the enums as appropriate and described in [the documentation](https://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.2.x/en/administration_guide.html#ADMIN.CUSTOMIZE.ENUMS) (you should still define the translations globally, including all valid values in the string)

To set a custom workflow, just set your current project as appropriate and use the *Manage | Manage Configuration | Workflow Transitions* to define it.